# dmesg giving error of SATA link down

Tags: dmesg

```
[ 1145.670001] ata6: EH complete
[ 1145.670454] ata6: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[ 1145.670459] ata6: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[ 1145.670463] ata6: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
[ 1145.670475] ata6: hard resetting link
[ 1147.909900] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
[ 1147.909925] ata6: EH complete
[ 1147.910884] ata6: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[ 1147.910893] ata6: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[ 1147.910900] ata6: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
[ 1147.910918] ata6: hard resetting link
[ 1150.253721] ata6: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
[ 1150.253742] ata6: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 8 secs
[ 1157.957244] ata6: hard resetting link
```

Comment: Looking at just an error, it looks like you have a failing SATA port. Are there any other symptoms other than dmesg?

Comment: Is this a new error? Does the system stop working when this error occurs? Is your hard drive set to spin down or sleep on idle? What brand/size is the HDD?

Comment: @Minty I am not able to login into any TTY terminal as well.The screen continously gives this error.

Comment: @heynnema https://pastebin.com/nm2Aj9TH My HDD specs. This happened after upgrading to ubuntu 18.04.The system doesnt stops though.

Comment: Show me the `terminal` output of `grep -i ncq /var/log/syslog*`, and `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*`, and `grep -i ata /var/log/syslog*`. Ping me at @heynnema

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XabE0eza
https://pastebin.com/18Pbd1Au
https://pastebin.com/iue59E4r

Comment: @heynnema I have attached the outputs in respective order in the previous comments.Can let me know what is exactly happening

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now the serious questions... is this a desktop or laptop? Do you hot-swap drives? Are these 2.5" or 3.5" drives? What brand HDD (Western Digital)? Are these connected to SATA 1 or 2 or 3 controllers? Have you checked that you have the latest BIOS firmware for your motherboard? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: I am using a Laptop with 2.5 inch Western Digital HDD. These are connected to  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s). Yes I do have latest BIOS frmware.

Comment: Is this WD HDD original to this laptop, or have you replaced/upgraded the HDD?

Comment: See https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?h=p1&ID=10477&lang=en&p=702. You may have a SATA cable issue, or a bad HDD.

Comment: Please use @heynnema when sending me comments, or I may miss them.